# Python sorted() skip row with empty coloumn

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have a CSV delimited by a '|'.  I am trying to read the CSV, sort by the 8th column, and output the sorted data as a standard CSV to the stdout.  The issue is that some rows in input CSV do not have an 8 column.  Those rows without a column 8 can be skipped entirely.  Right now when it hits a row without a column 8 it throws the error "list index out of range".  If I could just get it to continue and ignore that row it would be perfect.

Any help would be appreciated.  Certainly willing to change the block of code entirely.

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as openFile:
    reader = csv.reader((x.replace('\0','') for x in openFile), delimiter='|')
    col = 8
    sortedReader = sorted(reader, key=lambda k: (k[col] is None, k[col] == "", k[col]), reverse=True) # This was my attempted solution found on Google/StackOverflow.  Does not work. 
    csvout = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=',')
    for row in sortedReader:
        try:
            csvout.writerow(row)
        except:
            sys.stderr.write('[!] Error in row')
            sys.stderr.write(row)
            continue
```

Comment: By "continue and ignore that row" do you mean to discard the row?

Comment: Yes I do mean discard the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just filter the rows before sorting

```
filteredRows = filter(lambda x: len(x) > col, reader)
```

Comment: I prefer `filteredrows = [row for row in reader if len(row) > col]`.  Then `filteredrows.sort(...)`